# Server does not read messages from client sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I made an application with a connection between a client and a server. I am trying to have a conversation between them.

The client is able to receive messages from the server and then send the message. But the server is unable to receive messages from the client. can someone help

CLIENT

```
            System.out.println("Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
            System.out.println("Connected...");
            final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            String sendMessage = message;
            String  receiveMessage = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("server said " + receiveMessage);

            out.write(sendMessage);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

SERVER

```
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Accepting...");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected...");  
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            sendMessage = message;

            out.write(message);

            System.out.println("message to client: " + message);

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);

            System.out.println(bf.ready());

            if(bf.ready()){
                String messageClient = bf.readLine();
                System.out.println(messageClient);
            }
        }
```

Comment: On the server side, `message` must end with a newline character, as you're using `readLine` on the client side. Also, you're not flushing the server side when writing.

Comment: What does `ready()` print? From the docs of `InputStreamReader`: "*True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input*". Since the server is awaiting data from the client, I would expect blocking to occur, causing `ready()` to return `false`. Since you only read when `ready()` is true, the data is never read.

Comment: just ```readline()``` in blocking mode without checking for ```ready()```. It looks like you discard client message "long before" client is able to send it

Comment: I removed the `ready()` and when I run it still does not show on the server.

Comment: Are you sure your variable ```message``` is not empty ? - You did not include the code which declares and initializes it. Also please use @ to alert the person you are talking to.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny  the `message` is not empty.

Comment: use sniffer at client and server side to see what is going on. I wonder whether underlying implementation calls ```shutdown(socket, 1 or 2)```. if this is the case then client socket could be closed with option to discard any data which is queued for transmission ... Also you can add sleep 1 second after flush to test an idea about shutdown...

Comment: It's probably still waiting for line termination. You are calling `BufferedReader#readLine`, but you are using `PrintWriter#write`. `readLine()` will only succeed if it receives a line terminator. I don't see where you're sending any line terminators. Why not use `PrintWriter#println`?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny Using a sniffer would be quite a jump for a situation like this. Always start at the debugger. Even if he were able to sniff the data, he wouldn't be able to determine how the data is invalid, so that info wouldn't be of use to him. Instead, he should question why his program "hangs" when receiving data server-side. That would lead him to documented sources, which will reveal the line termination issue he is having. A debugger would make it pretty clear where the program is hanging/"not responding".

Comment: You were right. I put the line terminator and now my code works. thanks. @VinceEmigh